# Windows Phone Call States

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I born today for windows Phone Development , Hope I will get new things and new ideas with good comments from community,I want to know is there any way in windows phone API I can detect call states ? I am coming from android development ,In android there is Phone State Listener and for calling that gives three states like Idle,off-hook and ringing ,is there any way I can detect same thing in windows phone ?

Comment: Windows Phone platform does not give access to Call states and SMS stored in the phone, you can send SMS or Make call but you still need the user input to confirm the action

Comment: Hi @MarcinJuraszek and Harshit this link application looks reading call states ? http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/call-recorder/0ae54c27-41f6-43eb-8b91-61a7f95e01a3

Comment: That application is fully manual - you have to launch the app, start recording and end it when the call is over by yourself. Still no API :)

Comment: Ohh , I read the now with peer view yes that is as you type . thanks @MarcinJuraszek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API for anything regarding calls.

Comment: hi @ MarcinJuraszek,@Harshit and Igor Kulman thanks for your comments , if anyone have a look there is an application  http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/call-recorder/0ae54c27-41f6-43eb-8b91-61a7f95e01a3   looks this application getting the state of phone calls ?

Comment: @aftab according to the app description it just records sound using the microphone, so you have to run it after you start a call, turn the loundspeaker on and start recording

Comment: Hi @Igor Kulman thanks,but here is one different problem  can I detect user press call button in windows phone ? or can I know user incoming calls ?