# how to know programmatically when a last call was made to a specific number

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

is there a way i can know programmatically when last call was made to a specific number.Some thing like:

```
aCallDetailObj = getCallDetail("1234567890");
aDateTimeObj = aCallDetailObj.datetime;
```

in andriod, windows mobile and iOS(looks suspicious).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such API in order to access call details in `Windows Phone`.

[Windows Phone Call States](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788130/)